# Expand dataframe by lookup in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
engine       id
F1 D2 J3     100234
F1 D2 J3     100238
K2 JM F2     200788
K2 JM F2     200790

df2
engine       id
F1 D2 J3     100234
F1 D2 J3     100244
K2 JM F2     200788
K2 JM F2     200850
K2 JM F2     200690
```

I would like to extend df1 with rows from df2 that are not found in df1 for that engine and id combination. Resulting df would not contain duplicates and would look something like this:

```
engine       id
F1 D2 J3     100234
F1 D2 J3     100238
K2 JM F2     200788
K2 JM F2     200790
F1 D2 J3     100244
K2 JM F2     200850
K2 JM F2     200690
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` by specifying your two columns and with `how="outer"`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['engine', 'id'], how='outer')
```

Output:

```
     engine      id
0  F1 D2 J3  100234
1  F1 D2 J3  100238
2  K2 JM F2  200788
3  K2 JM F2  200790
4  F1 D2 J3  100244
5  K2 JM F2  200850
6  K2 JM F2  200690
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an outer join

```py
out = df1.join(df2, on=['engine', 'id'], how='outer')
```